# WinUSB application or user-mode driver as a filter driver for USB analysis/sniffer/trending

Tags: windows, usb, driver, sniffer

A question to maybe some who have worked extensively with WinUSB APIs or user mode USB drivers - can the WinUSB API or a user mode driver be used as a passive observer of USB connections, capturing notification of interrupts, control requests, data transfers, etc. without interfering with other applications (such as iTunes) which would obviously require concurrent access to the device at the same time my application is monitoring the connection and displaying data on it?

Or do you pretty much have to write a kernel-mode filter driver and inject yourself in the USB stack in order to make that happen?

In the past, there have been a few credible options (libusb-win32 and usbsnoop to be specific) though both are built around the old DDK, not the Windows Driver Foundation, and are not really supported on a regular basis any more. I'm hesitant to build something significant around them, as a result.

Comment: The more I think about it, the less likely I think it's possible. I probably need a filter driver in the kernel....

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must write a filter driver. There is no other way to intercept traffic generated by other devices. And you can use newer versions of the DDK, that is, KMDF for this task. It will make your life easier. But I think it will be cheaper and more effective just to get a hardware bus analyzer.

There is [a good overview by OSR](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=533). You must signed in to read this, but I strongly advice to sign in anyway if you are going to do any kernel mode development.

Answer (score 2):

The core USB drivers in Windows 7 have ETW trace points, so you can sniff traffic that way (blog post *[ETW in the Windows 7 USB core stack](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-usb-blog/bg-p/MicrosoftUSBBlog)*), but it is a bit kludgy and has some limitations like only tracing the first 32 bytes of each packet.

I have made a USB filter driver (KMDF) that is pretty easy to use (IMHO): http://code.google.com/p/busdog/

Comment: Oh, so it's YOUR driver! It crashed my system, and I've spent like 9 hours repairing the OS. Is it the last version at http://code.google.com/p/busdog/ ?

Answer (score 0):

USB Sniffer allows you to display, record and analyze all the data transferred between any USB device connected to your PC and applications. Also you can recover transferred data (for some file types).

The resulted project includes such components: Driver, Common library, GUI.
http://tellmeword.com/5zu2z5

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing on this question, it's worth noting that Wireshark makes use of https://desowin.org/usbpcap/ this purpose.